# Force browser to keep focus on a specific element

Tags: html, animation, webkit

I just finished a web app for iOS using HTML5 and CSS webkit animations.

Lets say I have element "A" which follows my finger when I drag anywhere on the screen. I have noticed some dropped frames when element A follows my finger. This is only noticeable on iPad. If I keep touching element A, it is A LOT better at following my touch move without dropping frames but if I touch anything else rather than element A and comeback to element A then element A drops frames big time trying to follow my finger as if browser lost focus on the element because I tapped some place else.

Is there a way to force the browser to keep the focus on element A so that it doesn't drop frames?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on the code you use to move element A or what this other element is that is taking focus. Code would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically cancel the `blur` event by refocusing the element. Here's how to do it using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(element).blur(function () {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function () { self.focus(); }, 20);
    });
});
```

Comment: i added that and it made no difference. I put a console.log right after "var self = this" and it never gets trigger meaning the blur() event is never called and Im clicking everywhere else but I cant get this function to print a single console.log.

Comment: @user1791848 add the event handler on $(document).ready(). Updating the example

Comment: its on document ready it just doesnt work even after i put tabindex and everything else to make sure that iOS reads the blur and focus events. I dont think mobile Safari knows anything about these events when it applies to divs.

Comment: Divs aren't focusable elements. So you cannot be gaining or losing focus there. You were saying you use an anchor.

Comment: by element "A" i mean element "X" or "Y" or whatever just any random element. It is a div, positioned absolute that follows touchmove. I can force focus action on a div through tabindex(it is supported by some browsers) however mobile safari does not seem to support it. So i have no way to know when the div is taking the browsers attention or not.